# Adding CSS in my python File to custom extracted data frame

Tags: python, html, css, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a panda data frame that I am used to visualize in Excel and that I would like to transform into HTML format. However, on Excel my cells have specific colors and the "to html" method allows me to transform my Data Frame to HTML format but it has no style and I would like to add some CSS to it in my python file in order to make my data frame "stylized".

One of my ideas would be to exploit an attribute of the "to html" method, namely the class attribute which allows to add classes to the resulting HTML table. However, I don't know how to store these classes in my python file upstream to give them as attribute to my HTML table afterwards.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? Note that I am not opposed to other ways of working to achieve the goal but the one proposed is the most realistic one I have encountered so far.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you read the pandas documention. The User Guide Table Visualization has numbers examples of exactly what you want.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.